# Algorithm to generate unique unicode characters of minimum length

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, unicode

I have a problem set where i have to insert a unique unicode character (or set of characters) to each record in Sql server. Is there any way to do that using identity specification or any other way to get it?

The algorithm will return unicode equivalent of :

```
[1],[2],[3]...[128],[1][1],[1][2],[1][3],....[1][128]
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Is `[1]` the same as `NCHAR(1)` and so on?

Comment: Yes. It is Char(1) and [1][1] represent two of them

Comment: So where does the minimum length bit come into it?

Comment: Btw, do you realize that the resulting strings will not all be visually distinguishable, due to homoglyphs? For that matter, if you use all possible numbers in the range of NCHAR then they won't even all be valid Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will generate the list of characters you are looking for:

```
SELECT REPLICATE(NCHAR(127), [ROW_NUMBER] / 128) + CHAR([ROW_NUMBER] - ([ROW_NUMBER] / 128) * 128)
    FROM (
        SELECT [ROW_NUMBER] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [e].[EmployeeKey])
            FROM [dbo].[DimEmployee] [e]) [sub]
```

---

**EDIT** Changed `CHAR` to `NCHAR`

Comment: actually, this will add [0],...,[127],[127][0],...,[127][127],[127][127][0],...[127][127][127],...